# FBX export: some NLA actions are broken

Tags: animation, export, unity, .fbx, nla-editor

I'm having a weird issue with exporting an FBX from Blender to Unity with different skeletal animations as action stashes.  Some of the animations show fine in Unity, but others  seem to only have animation on the root bone, so the character's moving around as a whole while being frozen in a pose.  I can't figure out what the difference is between the different animations that's making some work and others not.  Any help would be greatly appreciated.

(I would attach the blender file, but I can't figure out how)

Answer (score 0):

Someone helped me figure it out.  "Resample Curves" in the model import settings in Unity was turned on, and for some reason turning that off resolved the issue.

Comment: Usually this kind of issue is caused because a difference in the animation data or its interpretation can happen at any stage between export and final use. Hence, the common practice is to bake everything every single frame, using only spline interpolation, no constraints, key everything that should be, and so on. Normally if you do that, you rarely need to fiddle with import settings or anything in the game engine, aside from some rare specific needs.